# Git Bash not clear history

Tags: history, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash

I use window 10. I want to use `fc` to compare file, but it shows error:

> bash: fc: history specification out of range

I went to clear git history using `history -c`

It did clear history but when reopen git bash again, but all the history still there.

How can I clear git bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447295/where-is-the-bash-history-for-the-root-user-saved) if you enter `echo $HISTFILE` at the prompt it will output the location of the history file. You can manually navigate to this file and delete it in Windows Explorer.

In my instance the path was:

```
/c/Users/username/.bash_history
```

[image: Screenshot of the bash history location on Windows 10]

Comment: You could just echo a blank into the file, overwriting it `echo '' > $HISTFILE`

Comment: @djsmiley2k that is just a write blank to a new file call $HISTFILE. It is not overwrite the .bash_history